# Excel T88 error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

When a client opens an Excel 2013 file she will get this error.

[image]

I have tried to reset Excel and also an Office 2013 Repair but to no avail. Any ideas on what creates this?

Comment: How do you know its an error? It looks like that's the "name" of the selected cell. Does the workbook contain any macros or VBA code?

Comment: The "*error*" that you are referring to (in your picture) appears above the page layout icons in excel? This is a very strange place for the error to appear. Can you provide more details on this. What OS are u using?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like an error, it looks like the Excel window needs to be enlarged. T88 is a named range, and that is the name box at the top left and the green is the status bar when shrunk to a tiny window. Click Maximize or drag the bottom right window.